# how to slide jcarousel manually

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-jcarousel

i am using jcarousel in drupal as below:

```
jcarousel_add('#jcarousel',
    array('vertical' => false, 'scroll' => 3, 'horizontalDirection' => $direction,
        'initCallback' => 'slCarousel_initCallback')

    );
```

now to ask the question as simple as possible: how can i slide the carousel manually?? something like

```
jQuery("#jcarousel").jcarousel().next();
```

by the way,,, when i run this script **jQuery("#jcarousel").jcarousel().next();** in firebug i got this in the console of firebug

```
>>> jQuery("#jcarousel").jcarousel().next();
[]
```

I have tried this as well in firebug console

```
var carousel = jQuery("#jcarousel").data('jcarousel');
//alert (carousel);
carousel.next();
```

and got

```
>>> var carousel = jQuery("#jcarousel").data('jcarousel'); carousel.next()
TypeError: carousel is undefined
```

and the result of alert(carousel) was the word **undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... i fixed it by creating global variable and then assigning the value of the carousel to it

```
var global_jc="";
function slCarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
        global_jc=carousel;
....
}
```

and then wherever i want to use next manually i use this

```
global_jc.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the carousel's id is `jcarousel`? The plugin's documentation suggests `jcarousel_add()` takes a class name as the first parameter. If that's the case you can access it with `$( '.jcarousel' )` if you change it to `jcarousel_add( "jcarousel", ... )`. Inspect the carousel element or check the page source to see the id and classes.

Comment: to view real example of it: http://www.albawaba.com/somalia-starvation-ramadan-surplus-wastage-387943
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
jQuery('#jcarousel').jcarousel("next");
```

EDIT: Calling $(foo).jcarousel() with no arguments returns a jQuery object, so calling next() on that will return the next sibling of the carousel.  This function: http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: it didn't work :( to view real example of it: http://www.albawaba.com/somalia-starvation-ramadan-surplus-wastage-387943
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I'm not sure why that didn't work.  You can always simulate a click on the next button: `jQuery(".jcarousel-next").click();`.  That worked when I ran it in the Chrome console.  You can also reverse it by simulating a click on the previous button: `$(".jcarousel-prev").click();`